# How to merge videos captured with avcapturesession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, avcapturesession

i have captured videos by following Method:
"`[movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputFileURL recordingDelegate:self];`".

i have stored this "`outputFileURL`" in an `NSMutableArray`.

and i get "`outputFileURL`" is like this:

```
"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CB052F49-E9CA-4588-9661-BE8396C96AA3/Documents/output_2016-07-30_10-37-47.mov"
```

Now I want to merge these videos stored in `NSMutableArray`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the sollution...
convert outputFileURL to Avasset using
 AVAsset *track = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[_arrVideo objectAtIndex:i]];
and Now with Avasset u can merge videos..